# Calling inner function in Nested Scopes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS and am wondering, is there a way to return the function bar() or buz() by without returning foo()? For example, if I wanted to return the function bar(); to get 2, could I do that? Would it be something like foo().bar(); ?

```js
// Nested Scopes
function foo() {  // can only access itself
  var a = 1;

  function bar() {  // access to foo(), not buz()
    var b = 2;

    function buz() {   // access to bar() and foo()
      var c = 3;

      console.log(a, b, c);  // 1, 2, 3
    }
    buz();
    console.log(a, b);  // 1, 2
  }
  bar();
  console.log(a);  // 1
}
foo();  // 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without returning foo()"? Do you mean without `console.log(a);` executing?

Comment: I had been trying to do what @Xufox answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but it’s quite over-complicated.

The basic syntax is:

```
foo().bar().buz();
```

Where-ever you add another `()` after an existing one, it’ll print that level out. See the snippet for examples.

```js
// Nested Scopes
function foo() { // can only access itself
  var a = 1;

  function bar() { // access to foo(), not buz()
    var b = 2;

    function buz() { // access to bar() and foo()
      var c = 3;

      return (function() {
        console.log(a, b, c);
      });
    }

    return (function() {
      var tmp = function() {
        console.log(a, b);
        return {
          buz: buz
        };
      };
      tmp.buz = buz;
      return tmp;
    })();
  }

  return (function() {
    var tmp = function() {
      console.log(a);
      return {
        bar: bar
      };
    };
    tmp.bar = bar;
    return tmp;
  })();
}


foo().bar().buz(); // (nothing)
foo().bar()().buz(); // 1, 2
foo()().bar()().buz(); // 1  // 1, 2
foo()().bar().buz()(); // 1  // 1, 2, 3
foo()().bar()().buz()(); // 1  // 1, 2  // 1, 2, 3
```

This kind of abuses the fact that you can assign properties to anything in JavaScript, including functions.

- `foo` is a function that refers to the outer `foo`.
- `foo()` is another function that refers to that inner `tmp` which has a `bar` property that refers to the inner `bar` function.
- `foo()()` actually calls that inner `tmp` function but still leaves you with an object that has a `bar` property that again refers to the inner `bar` function.

This approach is basically the same for `bar`.

For `buz`, however, `(something).buz()` is just a function, without any extra properties and `(something).buz()()` doesn’t return anything, because that’s the final level.

Comment: Are the IIFEs just there to hide `tmp`? It does look a bit over-complicated.

Comment: @4castle Basically yes. Maybe `tmp` can just be a normal variable before the `return`. I’m not sure what could happen then… This can probably be improved…

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. You can return an object at each stage which holds the function, or you can return the function itself. This utilizes what's called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
function foo() {
  var a = 1;
  
  function bar() {
    var b = 2;
    
    function buz() {
      var c = 3;
      console.log(a, b, c);
    }
    
    console.log(a, b);
    return { buz: buz };
  }
  
  console.log(a);
  return { bar: bar };
}

foo().bar().buz();
```

Comment: But then you can't call `bar()` without it also running the `foo()` functionality (i.e., you can't log "1 2" without also logging "1"). Maybe making the inner functions to be properties would work better: `foo.bar()`...

Comment: @nnnnnn I can't actually think of a way of implementing that without calling `foo`. How do you assign those properties?

Comment: I'm not sure. My initial thought was "OK, just call `foo` as part of the setup", but that would have the side effect of logging stuff to the console (or doing whatever some real-world functions do) before any "client" code called the functions.

Comment: P.S. Even if you add some first-time-initialisation code, the behaviour still isn't great because the `foo.bar` and `foo.bar.buz` properties refer to functions that belong to the closure of the *first* call to `foo`: https://jsfiddle.net/bzbdhnd2/

Answer (score 0):

you do this more like setting a variable.

`var foo = {`

`bar: function() {`
   `return 3;`
`}`
`}`

`console.log(foo.bar());`